# Create user on Postgres 9.5 using FreeBSD and Vagrant

Tags: postgresql, vagrant, freebsd

I am trying to create a user in Postgresql 9.5 on FreeBSD 11. I am also trying to automate the whole thing with Vagrant and I have almost succeeded except for the creation of the user. I am using the createuser command with a password, and with that, I have attempted to use expect command in order to send the password to the prompt but I continue to receive the following error message:

"*default: createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist*"

Here is the code sample that I am using:

```
# Create the database and the user
PASS=password
expect << EOF

spawn createuser -sdrP capstone
expect "Enter password for new role:"
send "${PASS}\r"

expect "Enter it again:"
send "${PASS}\r"

expect eof;
EOF
```

I am not too sure what else to try in regards to overcome this error, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Do not run this script as root.
By default user "pgsql" has the permissions.
Switch to user:

```
su -l pgsql
```

Then run your expect script.